Evaluating integral via two different methods
I am trying to evaluate
\begin{equation}
I = 
\int_{-\Lambda}^{\Lambda}
\frac{x^2}{x^2 + y^2} d x,
\qquad 0< y < \Lambda
\end{equation}
via usual methods and contour integration. On one had, we find
\begin{equation}
I_1 = 
2\Lambda - 2y\ {\rm arctan}(\Lambda/y)
.
\end{equation}
However, using contour integration (closing the contour in the upper half-plane) gives
\begin{equation}
\oint_C \frac{z^2}{z^2 + y^2} dz = 2\pi i \cdot \frac{iy}{2} = -\pi y
.
\end{equation}
Isolating the semicircular curve with radius $\Lambda$ and taking $z = \Lambda \exp (i\theta)$
\begin{equation}
\int_{C_\Lambda}\frac{z^2}{z^2 + y^2} dz = i\int_0^\pi \frac{\Lambda^3e^{3i\theta}}{\Lambda^2 e^{2i\theta} + y^2} d\theta 
= 
-
\left[
2\Lambda - 2y\ {\rm arctan}(\Lambda/y)
\right]
.
\end{equation}
Using,
\begin{equation}
\oint_C \frac{z^2}{z^2 + y^2} dz 
=
\int_{-\Lambda}^{\Lambda}
\frac{x^2}{x^2 + y^2} d x
+
\int_{C_\Lambda}\frac{z^2}{z^2 + y^2} dz
\end{equation}
leads to
\begin{equation}
I_2 
=
-\pi y
+
\left[
2\Lambda - 2y\ {\rm arctan}(\Lambda/y)
\right]
.
\end{equation}
In principle, $I_1 = I_2$ however, as seen above, there is an extra factor from Cauchy's residue theorem. How do I reconcile this difference?

Related Phys.SE post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/837757/2451

The difference is caused by the fact that you are treating the arctangent function as if it were real, whereas in reality arctangent is a bit more of a difficult function to deal with when extended to the complex plane.
Unfortunately, it has branch cuts (which you can see here).
Therefore, it is not correct to just evaluate $\arctan(\frac{\Lambda}{y})-\arctan(\frac{-\Lambda}{y})$ in your calculations, as your curve, as you will see if you look at the helpful diagram on that website, crosses a branch cut on the imaginary axis above $i$.
Instead, what you must do is take the branch of arctangent s.t:
$\arctan(z)=\frac{1}{2i}\ln|{\frac{z-i}{z+i}}|+\frac{1}{2}\arg{\frac{z-i}{z+i}}$, with $\arg(z)\in [0,2\pi]$.
That effectively rotates where the branch cuts are on the diagram; now they lie on the real axis. Now, you can apply the method you were doing but to the integral;
$$\int_{C_\Lambda}\frac{z^2}{z^2 + y^2} dz = i\lim_{p\to \pi}\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^p \frac{\Lambda^3e^{3i\theta}}{\Lambda^2 e^{2i\theta} + y^2} d\theta +i\lim_{q\to 0}\int_{q}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\Lambda^3e^{3i\theta}}{\Lambda^2 e^{2i\theta} + y^2} d\theta $$ using the newly defined  $\arctan(z)$ above and you should get the right answer.
Notice that I introduced the limits; that's because the branch cuts would still technically cause an issue on the real axis. But if I take the limit, I remove that problem.
Upon doing this , you will see that the missing $-\pi y$ appears.
